# Unexpected "Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo, react-dom, react-hooks

I am using a simple `useState()` hook in a functional component.

When I run, I get an error stating:

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

I have updated both react & react-dom to be on the same versions (16.8.1).

The functional component that uses hooks:

```js
const AuthForm = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

  return (
    <Paper square>
      <Tabs
        value={value}
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
        onChange={() => setValue(value)}
      >
        <Tab label="Active" />
        <Tab label="Active" />
      </Tabs>
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

The code that is using AuthForm:

```js
import AuthForm from "./Auth/AuthForm";

const App = props => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <AuthForm />
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.27",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-graphql": "^0.7.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "graphql": "^14.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.11",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.1",
    "react-apollo": "^2.4.1",
    "react-dom": "16.8.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.3.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config:

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./client/index.js",
  output: {
    path: "/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: "babel-loader",
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        resolve: {
          extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "client/index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

Most answers online just say to make sure react and react-dom are on the same version. Has anybody else hit this issue recently?

Comment: Please show the code that uses `AuthForm`.

Comment: I got this error when using mobx with hooks. So if you use mobx or any similar library, that could potentially cause this error.

Comment: it may be related to environment. say `reat-hot-loader` is [still incompatible](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088) with hooks since it transpiles functional components into class-based for its needs

Comment: @RyanCogswell Added it to original question

Comment: @skyboyer I've seen others mention this but I'm not using react-hot-loader.

Comment: Nothing in the code shown so far indicates any issue. Here's a sandbox with it working fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/5zj5o023vp

Comment: If you aren't calling `useState` from an inappropriate place, the main causes of this error are having multiple copies of react (e.g. due to a dependency that pulls in react as a dependency rather than a peerDependency) or react and react-dom versions out of sync with each other.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks so much for running that. I'm starting to wonder if it's an issue of having more than one copy of React in my app. Do you know how I can verify this?

Comment: react-apollo's devDependencies look a bit suspect: "react": "16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "16.8.1"

Comment: @RyanCogswell Where did you see 16.5.2?

Comment: Line 134: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/master/package.json

Comment: @RyanCogswell Great catch. Submitted an issue for it. Will report back.

Comment: Tracking issue: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2792

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, and I'm certain it's an issue with the environment as it is working in certain cases, and had been working previously to an unknown change. What's the best way to determine if there are incorrect or too many versions of react running? My package.json has ^16.8.0 for both react and react-dom and from what I can see in the yarn.lock the correct versions are being used (16.8.2)